# Store [String] in NSUserDefaults

Tags: ios, swift, string, nsarray, nsuserdefaults

I want to save a Swift Style String Array into NSUserDefaults, but acutally the "if" statement in the code says that returnValue is always nil.

Later in the code (iOS 8) I want to use "food += ["spaghetti"] to add new entries.

```
var food : [String] {
    get {
        var returnValue : [String]? = NSUserDefaults.standardUserDefaults().objectForKey("food") as? [String]
        if returnValue == nil      //Check for first run of app
        {
            returnValue = ["muesli", "banana"]; //Default value
        }
        return returnValue!
    }
    set (newValue) {
        NSUserDefaults.standardUserDefaults().setObject(newValue, forKey: "food")
        NSUserDefaults.standardUserDefaults().synchronize()
    }
}
```

Comment: i was also trying several things from this [link](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/24032863/swift-and-nsuserdefaults-exc-bad-instruction-when-user-defaults-empty) but it didn't bring up the solution

Comment: it seems your problem is you never save those values into the user defaults, because adding a new item to the array does not call the setter. you need to set the actual `food` directly somewhere (e.g. `food = ["such", "and", "such"]`) to get it saved.

Comment: I just tried your code in latest Xcode7 and Swift2.0, and it's actually perfect.

Comment: This is best example for NSUserDefault : http://iosdevcenters.blogspot.com/2016/05/save-data-using-nsuserdefaults-in-swift.html

Answer (score 33, accepted):

The following code should help you resolve your problem:

```
import UIKit

class ViewController: UIViewController {

    var food: [String] {
        get {
            if let returnValue = NSUserDefaults.standardUserDefaults().objectForKey("food") as? [String] {
                return returnValue
            } else {
                return ["muesli", "banana"] //Default value
            }
        }
        set {
            NSUserDefaults.standardUserDefaults().setObject(newValue, forKey: "food")
            NSUserDefaults.standardUserDefaults().synchronize()
        }
    }

    override func viewDidLoad() {
        super.viewDidLoad()

        print(food) // prints: ["muesli", "banana"] (at first launch)

        food = ["cake"]
        print(food) // prints: ["cake"]

        food += ["spaghetti"]
        print(food) // prints: ["cake", "spaghetti"]

        food = []
        print(food) // prints: []

        NSUserDefaults.standardUserDefaults().setObject(nil, forKey: "food")
        print(food) // prints: ["muesli", "banana"]
    }

}
```

---

However, with the previous code, if you set `food = []`, you will have a problem as `food` won't return `["muesli", "banana"]`. In order to avoid this, you may prefer the following code:

```
import UIKit

class ViewController: UIViewController {

    var food: [String] {
        get {
            if let returnValue = NSUserDefaults.standardUserDefaults().objectForKey("food") as? [String] {
                return returnValue == [] ? ["muesli", "banana"] : returnValue
            } else {
                return ["muesli", "banana"] //Default value
            }
        }
        set {
            NSUserDefaults.standardUserDefaults().setObject(newValue, forKey: "food")
            NSUserDefaults.standardUserDefaults().synchronize()
        }
    }

    override func viewDidLoad() {
        super.viewDidLoad()

        print(food) // prints: ["muesli", "banana"] (at first launch)

        food = ["cake"]
        print(food) // prints: ["cake"]

        food += ["spaghetti"]
        print(food) // prints: ["cake", "spaghetti"]

        food = []
        print(food) // prints: ["muesli", "banana"]

        NSUserDefaults.standardUserDefaults().setObject(nil, forKey: "food")
        print(food) // prints: ["muesli", "banana"]
    }

}
```

Comment: Curious, why would you declare food as [NSString] instead of [String]? You can convert to [NSString] for storage in NSUserDefaults, then return [String] when returning from NSUserDefaults.

Answer (score 13):

As stated in the [documentation](https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/documentation/Cocoa/Reference/Foundation/Classes/NSUserDefaults_Class/Reference/Reference.html#//apple_ref/occ/instm/NSUserDefaults/setObject:forKey:):

> For NSArray and NSDictionary objects, their contents must be property
>   list objects.

This means you need to convert your `String` objects to `NSString` when saving, something like this should work:

```
var food : [String] {
    get {
        var returnValue : [String]? = NSUserDefaults.standardUserDefaults().objectForKey("food") as? [String]
        if returnValue == nil      //Check for first run of app
        {
            returnValue = ["muesli", "banana"]; //Default value
        }
        return returnValue!
    }
    set (newValue) {
        //  Each item in newValue is now a NSString
        let val = newValue as [NSString]
        NSUserDefaults.standardUserDefaults().setObject(val, forKey: "food")
        NSUserDefaults.standardUserDefaults().synchronize()
    }
}
```

Comment: Seems like this is best since you're only converting to [NSString] for storage, while returning [String] from storage.

Answer (score 9):

In Swift 3.0

**Store**

```
UserDefaults.standard.set(newValue, forKey: "yourkey")
UserDefaults.standard.synchronize()
```

**Retrieve**

```
var returnValue: [NSString]? = UserDefaults.standard.object(forKey: "yourkey") as? [NSString]
```

**Remove**

```
UserDefaults.standard.removeObject(forKey: "yourkey")
```

Reference: [NSUserdefault objectTypes](http://www.codingexplorer.com/nsuserdefaults-a-swift-introduction/)

Answer (score 2):

**Set and Get NSUserDefault with function**

Use below function to globally use , declare in any class any use in whole app

**Declaratio**n

```
func setUserDefault(ObjectToSave : AnyObject?  , KeyToSave : String)
{
    let defaults = NSUserDefaults.standardUserDefaults()

    if (ObjectToSave != nil)
    {

        defaults.setObject(ObjectToSave, forKey: KeyToSave)
    }

    NSUserDefaults.standardUserDefaults().synchronize()
}

func getUserDefault(KeyToReturnValye : String) -> AnyObject?
{
    let defaults = NSUserDefaults.standardUserDefaults()

    if let name = defaults.valueForKey(KeyToReturnValye)
    {
        return name
    }
    return nil
}
```

### **How to call**

```
Classname_where_this_function_declare.sharedInstance.setUserDefault("value", KeyToSave: "key")**
```

Answer (score -1):

//

```
    class func saveCustomObject(_ object: AnyObject?, key: String) { 
      let encodedObject = NSKeyedArchiver.archivedData(withRootObject: object!) 
      let userDefaults = UserDefaults.standard userDefaults.set(encodedObject, forKey: key) 
      userDefaults.synchronize() 
    }
```

//

```
class func loadCustomObject(_ key: String) -> AnyObject? { 
   let userDefaults = UserDefaults.standard 
   if let userDefaultKey = userDefaults.object(forKey: key) { 
     let encodedObject = userDefaultKey as! NSData 
     return NSKeyedUnarchiver.unarchiveObject(with: encodedObject as Data)! as AnyObject? 
   } else {
     return nil 
   }
}
```

//

```
class func removeCustomObject(_ key: String) { // 
    let encodedObject = NSKeyedArchiver.archivedDataWithRootObject(object!) let userDefaults = 
    UserDefaults.standard userDefaults.removeObject(forKey: key) 
    userDefaults.synchronize()
 }
```

---

call Method

```
let aParams : [String : String] = [ "DeviceType" : "iOS", ]
CommonMethods.saveCustomObject(aParams as AnyObject?, key:Constants.kLoginData)
```

---