# NSUserDefaults is not saving my Array

Tags: ios, xcode, swift, nsuserdefaults

I made a to do list app and I got an array called `toDo` & a textView in each cell. I want the array to be saved in the `NSUserDefaults`, but whenever I quit the app and open it again - it doesn't save it.

Here is what I tried:

```
let def = NSUserDefaults.standardUserDefaults()
var key = "keySave"

        override func viewDidLoad() {
             super.viewDidLoad()
             def.setObject(toDo, forKey: "keySave")
        }
        func textViewDidEndEditing(textView: UITextView) {
            todoTableView.reloadData()
            def.setObject(toDo, forKey: "keySave")
        }
```

Comment: What is `def` in your code? And, for the `NSUserDefaults` objects, you have to call `synchronize` method after inserting objects, if you want your data saved.

Comment: sorry, I edited it - def is `NSUserDefaults.standardUserDefaults()`. And in iOS 8 you don't need to save it by `synchronize`.

Comment: what kind of objects stores `toDo` array? they're just Strings?

Comment: What are the objects in the array?

Comment: @FahriAzimov More specifically, `synchronize` writes the data to disk immediately. You don't need to call it in most cases.

Comment: @lucaslt89, Fogmeister - The `toDo` array is just Strings.

Comment: Yeah, sorry, missed the word "immediately".

Comment: Here you go... Swift Strings are not compatible with NSUserDefaults. You have to cast them to NSString. http://stackoverflow.com/questions/25420651/store-string-in-nsuserdefaults-swift Going to close as a duplicate question.

Comment: The lesson i do not use `NSUserDefaults` as a data model. Create a class with `NSCoding` support and archive to a file. Consider the name: NS**UserDefaults**, that does not sound like a data model.

Comment: @zaph I agree that one should use `NSUserDefaults` appropriately, but that's really not the cause of the problem here.

Comment: @Fogmeister I don't understand how the answer in the link is helping me.. Can you explain please?

Comment: Notice that was a comment, not an answer. @Fogmeister provided a solution. However, using a real data model would solve the problem and using `NSUserDefaults` is the cause of the problem.

Comment: @zaph Can you give an example of that?