# NSUserDefaults not saving in setter of class variable

Tags: ios, xcode, nsuserdefaults

When I try to save to NSUserDefaults by adding a setter to my class variable (in this case the `id` and `authToken` variables, the values don't seem to be saved. When I run with a breakpoint on, the getter of `id` and `authToken` always return nil even after setting them with a value.

```
class CurrentUser {

    static let defaultInstance = CurrentUser()

    func updateUser(id id: String, authToken: String) {
        self.id = id
        self.authToken = authToken
    }

    var authToken: String? {
        get {
            if let authToken = NSUserDefaults.standardUserDefaults().objectForKey("userAuthToken") {
                return (authToken as! String)
            } else {
                return nil
            }
        }
        set {
            NSUserDefaults.standardUserDefaults().setObject(authToken, forKey: "userAuthToken")
            NSUserDefaults.standardUserDefaults().synchronize()
        }
    }

    var id: String? {
        get {
            if let id = NSUserDefaults.standardUserDefaults().objectForKey("userId") {
                return (id as! String)
            } else {
                return nil
            }
        }
        set {
            NSUserDefaults.standardUserDefaults().setObject(id, forKey: "userId")
            NSUserDefaults.standardUserDefaults().synchronize()
        }
    }
}
```

However, when I pull the lines out to the updateUser function (one level higher), all works as expected.

```
class CurrentUser {

    static let defaultInstance = CurrentUser()

    func updateUser(id id: String, authToken: String) {
        NSUserDefaults.standardUserDefaults().setObject(id, forKey: "userId")
        NSUserDefaults.standardUserDefaults().synchronize()

        NSUserDefaults.standardUserDefaults().setObject(authToken, forKey: "userAuthToken")
        NSUserDefaults.standardUserDefaults().synchronize()
    }

    var authToken: String? {
        get {
            if let authToken = NSUserDefaults.standardUserDefaults().objectForKey("userAuthToken") {
                return (authToken as! String)
            } else {
                return nil
            }
        }
    }

    var id: String? {
        get {
            if let id = NSUserDefaults.standardUserDefaults().objectForKey("userId") {
                return (id as! String)
            } else {
                return nil
            }
        }
    }
}
```

Why would this be? What am I missing? Does the { set } run on a different thread / mode where NSUserDefaults isn't accessible?

Comment: Why not load/save during object lifetime and keep them as simple instance variables?  It's over-engineered.

Comment: @Droppy Can you explain a bit more what you mean by that.

Comment: Load the values during init and save during dealloc (or whatever its called in swift) and just keep the values as normal instance variables.  Alternatively have explicit load/save methods.  I doubt there is a need to sync to user-defaults every time they change.

Comment: You are using the variables as computed variables, so they don't actually have a value storage location.  So when you do `NSUserDefaults.standardUserDefaults().setObject(id, forKey: "userId")`, `id` doesn't really exist...  Change that to `NSUserDefaults.standardUserDefaults().setObject(newVal, forKey: "userId")`

Answer (score 1):

You must use `newValue` inside set method, value is still nil, or use `didSet` and then you can use variable.

Answer (score 0):

As Alex said, you must use newValue in set method. Moreover, you can refer to this link for more detail:
[Store [String] in NSUserDefaults (Swift)](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/25420651/store-string-in-nsuserdefaults-swift)