# Get NSUserDefault array

Tags: ios, xcode, casting, swift

I am trying to learn swift and wish to get an array from NSUser defaults.

```
let usersToDo = NSUserDefaults.standardUserDefaults().objectForKey("ToDoList");
```

In Java I could cast or something similar to an array so as to then call specific array functions on it.

How would this be done in swift?

Thanks

Comment: Apple has an eBook, available on the iTunes bookstore, that explains the Swift language. You should read it.

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/24032863/swift-and-nsuserdefaults-exc-bad-instruction-when-user-defaults-empty

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
var userDefaults = NSUserDefaults.standardUserDefaults()
var todo = userDefaults.objectForKey("todolist") as NSArray;

if let td = todo {
// Use td
} else {
// todo == nil
}
```